# Xpath to check multiple empty children

Tags: xpath, multiple-instances

With the following xml, I'm trying to return `true` or `false` depending on whether all `<CrucialNumber>` elements are empty or not:

```
<Invoice>
  <Details>
    <LIN1>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Product>Test XML</Product>
      <CrucialNumber/>
    </LIN1>
    <LIN1>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Product>Test XML</Product>
      <CrucialNumber/>
    </LIN1>
    <LIN1>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Product>Test XML</Product>
      <CrucialNumber>123456</CrucialNumber>
    </LIN1>
  </Details>
</Invoice>
```

The data-type of the `CrucialNumber` element is `string`.

So far, these are the xpath expressions I have tried:

```
string-length(//CrucialNumber/*) > 0;    

not(//CrucialNumber/*[text()]);

./Details/LIN1[*]/CrucialNumber[1] = "";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
not(.//CrucialNumber/node())
```

should do it, it will be true if and only if either (a) there are no `CrucialNumber` descendant elements at all, or (b) all the descendant `CrucialNumber` elements are empty.

Comment: Thanks @Ian...This is the solution. Meanwhile, I also tested with `not(.//CrucialNumber/text())`. Thanks again.